# Create Multiple Boxes from One Box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, box

I am trying to create multiple boxes from one box. But I am new to HTML, not know how to do it.
What I need:
I need one box; by clicking on it, two new boxes will create, and next time four boxes will create.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
  console.log(elements[i]);
}
```

```css
.box { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  background: steelblue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: so you have 1 box by click 2 new box, total is 3 boxes to display. by click again 4 new boxes, total 7 boxes to display right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt (vanilla JS) :

```js
let boxesToCreate = 2;
createBoxesOnClick = (box) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < boxesToCreate; i ++){
      let newBox = document.createElement("div");
      newBox.classList.add("box");
      newBox.textContent=boxesToCreate + i;
      createBoxesOnClick(newBox);
      document.body.appendChild(newBox);
    }
    boxesToCreate = boxesToCreate * 2;
  })    
}

let firstBox = document.querySelector(".box");
createBoxesOnClick(firstBox);
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.box { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  background: steelblue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
```

I'm not sure of the best way to register a new element to an event so I made a function to register new boxes to `onClick` :

- I create x (`boxToCreate`) boxes
- Add the `box` class
- Add text to check the box number
- Register the box to onClick() with the function
- Append the new box to the container (body)
- Multiply `boxToCreate` by 2. Note that with your question we can't tell if you want to increase the number of created each time by x2 or +2, you just need to change `boxesToCreate = boxesToCreate * 2` by `boxesToCreate = boxesToCreate + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code once I used `jQuery` for it.

**Here is code snippet:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(){
    $(".box").clone().eq(0).insertAfter( ".box" );
    var i = 1;
    $('.box').each(function() {
        $(this).html(i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

```css
.box { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid green; 
    background: steelblue; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will increase boxes + 2 from previews generated

if you like you can change box_num += 2 to box_num *= 2 that will increase boxes * 2 from previerws generated

```js
let box_num = 2
let num = 1

$(document).on('click', '.box', function(){

let html = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < box_num; i++){
    html += `<div class="box">${num + 1}</div>` 
    num++
  }
  
  $('.container').append(html)
  box_num += 2
  
})
```

```css
.box { 
            width: 100px; 
            height: 100px; 
            border: 1px solid green; 
            background: steelblue; 
            display: inline-block
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><div class="box">1</div></div>
```